# What is the function of this ~* syntax in a sql query?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am trying to understand a script to implement new functions and options.
In order to search in sql tables they used the following syntax

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT \"Name\", \"FileName\", \"Status\", lower(\"Name\") FROM \"" . $SearchedTable . "\" WHERE ";

$sqlquery=$sqlquery." (\"Name\" ~* '".$text[$i]."' OR \"DNA\" ~* '".$text[$i]."')";
```

- What I would like to know is why they use \"Name\" (I read somewhere that it has something to do with sql injections).
- I also couldn't find the reason why to use this syntax ~* instead of =. Or does it means something else?

Comment: Are you sure this is `mysql` and not `postgres`? `~` is used in mysql as a bitwise operator as well as a negation operator in a fulltext search. Neither of those appear to be in play here. Where in postgresql a `~` is a regular expression operator which makes a lot more sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks, I adapted it. I didn't want to give my full query. I wouldn't be very clear.

Comment: This is Postgresql not mysql. Search for pattern matching operators.

Comment: If you want to avoid sql injection then read a tutorial about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General note: Your current query uses string concatenation, and therefore is prone to SQL injection.  The best fix on your PHP side would be to use a prepared statement.

That being said, your SQL syntax appears to be Postgres, not MySQL.  Here is the rough query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, FileName, Status, lower(Name)
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name ~* ? OR DNA ~* ?;
```

The `~*` operator in Postgres does case insensitive regex matching.  So, for example, to match any `Name` which starts with `mi`, you could use:

```
WHERE Name ~* '^mi'
```

Therefore, what you should be binding to the two placeholders are regular expressions.

Comment: My columns are containing full sentences. So, for example I wound to find the row containing my tables contains full sentences" . This operator will find this row when I my sqlquery contains for example "WHERE Name ~* full"?

Comment: You would need single quotes around `full`, but yes, it would.  You probably would also want to surround `full` with word boundaries, to only match the full word and not as a substring.  So maybe use `WHERE Name ~* '\yfull\y'`.