# postgres. How to check if a field contains at least one substring from a list of substings?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, substring

I have a table like this

```
 one | two | three   |  code   | four 

-----+-------+-------+---------+--------

   0 | 21750 | 10110 | 1016916 |   20.0

   0 | 21750 | 10111 | 1017949 |   20.2 

   0 | 21750 | 10115 | 101792 |   21.0 

   0 | 21737 | 10110 | 100753 |   20.0  

   0 | 21737 | 10110 | 14343054 |   20.0
```

I want to extract all records in which the field `code` contains at least one of the following substrings:

794, 43, 17

How can I do it?

### UPDATE

I know I could achieve this by writing

```
select * from mytable where
code ilike '%794%' or
code ilike '%43%' or
code ilike '%17%';
```

but imagine that in the true case the matching substrings are given to my with the shape of an array ( e.g. `('794', '43', '17')` ) which  would have length > 100, so I don't want to rewrite this array into 100+ `WHERE` conditions, each one for each substring to be searched in the `code` field.

I have tryed with

```
select * from mytable where code && '{"794", "43", "17"}';
```

but it throws this error

[image]

HINT: No operator found with given name and argument types. You may need to convert types explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another solution, simple and beautiful, which I like more than any other one:

```
select * from mytable where
code  ~* '(794|43|17)' ;
```

where the  `~*` operator in Postgres does case insensitive regex matching (see [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53746264/7658051)).

That query is equivalent to

```
select * from mytable where
code ilike '%794%' or
code ilike '%43%' or
code ilike '%17%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use unnest() on your array for the input an map the content using a regex:

```
SELECT mytable.* 
FROM mytable
    JOIN unnest('{"794", "43", "17"}'::text[]) AS list(content) 
        ON code ~ content; -- regex
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating the where condition for each substring, you may use a cte that contains all the substrings and then do a join with your table as the following:

```
with matching_list as
(
  select s from
  (values('794'),('43'), ('17')) as t(s)
)
select t.* 
from table_name t join matching_list mch
on strpos(t.code::text, mch.s)>0 -- or (on t.code::text like concat('%', mch.s, '%'))
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/62pEI-Nj)

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the `code` field to text and then use `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE code::text LIKE '%794%' OR code::text LIKE '%43%' OR code::text LIKE '%17%';
```

If you have many substrings and want to avoid a lengthy `WHERE` clause, then load your substrings into a proper table:

```
Table: substrings
code
794
43
17
```

And use the following join with your original table to find matches:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN substrings t2
    ON t1.code::text LIKE '%' || t2.code || '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL "LIKE" operator combined with the "OR" operator to extract the records that contain any of the specified substrings in the "code" field.
In your example:

```
SELECT *
FROM *your_table*
WHERE code LIKE '%794%' OR code LIKE '%43%' OR code LIKE '%17%';
```

To know more about "LIKE" operator I recommend to look at some other example here: [SQL LIKE Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)